# How to use of code chunks as parameters to c preprocessor directives?

Tags: metaprogramming, wxwidgets, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to provide a macro with entire chunks of code as a parameter and expand it into the definition?

```
#define PATTERN(param,func)\
    chk=new wxCheckBox(page,wxID_ANY,param);\
    sizer->Add(chk,0,0,0);\
    chk->Bind(wxEVT_CHECKBOX,func);

PATTERN("checkbox 1",
 //piece of code
 [=](wxCommandEvent& event){
   wxMessageBox(wxT("test"),wxT(""),wxICON_INFORMATION);
  }
 //end of code
)
```

How to encapsulate code for these means?
I want to be able to do:

```
   #define DERIVATIVE(s)\
      PATTERN(...)
```

Comment: Generally this is possible. Do you get any compile errors?

Comment: the comma's would interfere wouldnt they? you'd end up with multiple additiona arguments. I could use __VAR_ARGS but I'd like to know if there's an elegant solution

Comment: Why not use a small static function for this?

Comment: What commas should interfere? PATTERN just has two arguments and you just provide two arguments.

Comment: `wxMessageBox(wxT("test"),wxT(""),wxICON_INFORMATION);` has 2 commas and CPP doesnt read braces afaik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using two sets of macros for this

```
#define TEMPLATE_CODE(INSERTME) \
  ... \
  INSERTME(); \
  ...

#define SPECIALIZED_CODE() \
  ...

TEMPLATE_CODE(SPECIALIZED_CODE);
```

As an example,

```
#define TEMPLATE_CODE(INSERTME, ARG) void sayhello(void) { INSERTME(ARG); }
#define OTHER_TEMPLATE(INSERTME, ARG) class myclass { INSERTME(ARG); }
#define FIRST_IMPL(ARG) cout << ARG << endl
#define WRAPPER() TEMPLATE_CODE(FIRST_IMPL, ARG)
OTHER_TEMPLATE(WRAPPER, "hello world")
#undef FIRST_IMPL
#undef WRAPPER
```

Comment: yes, but I need to use the TEMPLATE inside other macro's again, having to nest defines which would prove impossible afaik, I don't think I even could use include-based directives because the SPECIALIZED would be line-specific and not variable.

Comment: @aelgoa is my example what you were looking for?  If not, how would you adjust it to be what you desired?